# Update data table with new string

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, onchange

I have the following `TextChanged` event -

```
 protected void DataList1_SelectedTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox chk = (TextBox)sender;
        DataListItem item = (DataListItem)chk.NamingContainer;

        TextBox txt = (TextBox)DataList1.Items[item.ItemIndex].FindControl("aTextBox");
        string text = txt.Text;

        WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
        ws.updateA(text, newText)

    }
```

where the `ws.updateA` web method needs `text` which is the original text in the textbox and `newText` which is the text after the changed event has been fired.

My problem being how can I distinguish between the original text and the newText to use in the web method as the method is updating the data table with the new text uses the original to update?

The SQL is -

```
UPDATE table SET term='" + newText + "' WHERE termText= '" + text + "'
```

Comment: So you have the issue in your sql which needs the old value. That's nonsense since the database knows best of all the old value. To identify a record you normally use primary keys.

Comment: perhaps i need a better update statement?

Comment: You need a better database model. What is the primary key of this table? Normally you would use a consecutive number(in SQL-Server `IDENTITY(1,1)`) as PK, then you use this number as identifier for the record. Then the `term` column is unnecessary to identify it.

Comment: @Jambo That SQL is really vulnerable.

Comment: I realise now I should have been using the identity value instead of the original text :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really use a primary key to identify which row to update. Updating by a text string in the where clause isn't a good practice.

By the time `SelectedTextChanged` event is fired, the old value of the control is long overwritten in the page life cycle.

If it is critical to know the old value, you should persist in across PostBacks using the `ViewState`.

Refer: [How to: Save Values in View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)